# introducing synchronous chained execution in celery workflow

Tags: python, asynchronous, celery

Suppose there are 4 tasks `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4`. They are chained together as `T1.si() | T2.si() | T3.si() | T4.si()`. `T3` spawns further tasks `T30 .. T3n` asynchronously like `chord(T30,...,T3n)(reduce.s())`. I don't know `n` in advance (i.e., the no of subtasks `T3i`s that would be spawned).

I want `T4` to execute only after all of the `T3i..T3n` tasks complete. As expected, `T3` returns immediately due to the asynchronous behavior and then T4 starts executing before the chord is complete.

I could add a synchronous task that just does `T3.get()` before `T4`, but it will block one of the worker processes.

Is there a way to fix this design to avoid the blocking task, or a better design?

Comment: So I think the best option here is to change how you are using the `chord` functionality. Instead of chaining together `T3` and `T4`, use `T3` as the `chord` body and `T4` as the `chord` callback.

Answer (score 2):

I will improve @jenner-felton's comment a bit...

You may call it like this:

```
chain(T1.s(), T2.s(), T3.s(T4.s()))
```

e.g. `T4.s()` passed as one of parameters to the T3 task.

And T3 will run a `chord` itself with T4 passed as a callback.